# Error connecting to Oracle with Classic ASP on IIS7

Tags: oracle, iis-7, asp-classic, odbc, oledb

I just replaced the hard drive on my Windows 7 machine (my development computer). I did not have any issues with this working on the old hard drive, but I think I remember I had to change something or install something, but I do not remember.

The following code works perfectly on my live machine (Windows 2003 with IIS6).

```
OracleConn = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=TheUID;Password=ThePW;DSN=TheDB;DBQ=ORA_PRD1;"

SqlStr = "SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE Somefield = 'Something'"
Set Objrs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
Objrs.Open SqlStr, OracleConn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic,adCmdText
While Not Objrs.EOF
Response.Write "Some Stuff and whatever <br>"
Objrs.MoveNext
Wend
Objrs.Close
Set Objrs = Nothing
```

When I run it, I am getting the following error:

*Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'*

*[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed*

I did create a .udl file to get the connection string and to test the database connection and it works fine. I also have an app on my computer that uses the same ODBC drivers to connect to the same database and it works fine.

I dont have any issues connecting to an Access database at all. Connecting to Oracle seems to be the only issue I am having.

Comment: Could it be a 32 bit/64 bit issue - its often the case on Win 7.  This is a good resource for alternative connection strings  http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

Comment: I dont think so. It is the same connection string I have been using for years. The only thing that has changed is that I have a new hard drive.